# How to set view in matplolib FigureCanvas programmatically?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class MyFigure(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.canvas.setParent(self.widget)
        self.axis = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self.widget)

    def plot(self, x, y):
        self.axis.plot(x, y)
        self.canvas.draw()

    def set_view(self, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax):
        # how can I do that?
```

With the NavigationToolbar I can use *pan* and *zoom* to interactively set the view to a particular region of the plot in FigureCanvas.

How can I set the FigureCanvas view programmatically to a region (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
def set_view(self, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax):
    if self.toolbar._nav_stack() is None:
        # otherwise the zoomed view will be the first in the stack
        self.toolbar.push_current()
    # Call the _set_view method of the "Axes" instance
    self.axis._set_view((xlo, xhi, ylo, yhi))
    self.toolbar.draw()
    # add the new view to the navigation stack:
    self.toolbar.push_current()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change view limits using [matplotlib.pyplot.xlim](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html) or [matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html). For example:

```
def set_view(self, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax):
    self.axis.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
    self.axis.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
```

However, I don't how this interacts with FigureCanvas. Just test it.

Comment: This certainly works, but is not quite what I want.